# Canvas - How to draw the grid of the dots with the light source in the center?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I think it's usual question, but I have some problems with displaying dots in canvas. The first thing I'd like to know is how to draw dot like [this](http://s23.postimg.org/88qu4qfnb/Untitled_13.png) (please zoom it).
The second thing is, how to draw a shadow to each element of the grid of this dots, with the light source in the center.

What I have at this moment right [here](http://i41.tinypic.com/2jcvuc6.png):

**the part of my code:**

```
context.fillStyle = "#ccc";

context.shadowColor = '#e92772';
context.shadowOffsetX = 15;
context.shadowOffsetY = 15;

while (--e >= 1) {
    x -= z;
    if(x < 0) {
        x = z*w;
        y -= z;
    }
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 );
    outs = a[e];
}
```

Also, I've tried to use "context.arc();", but I think "context.fillRect();" is more easier. And one else moment, when I use "while (--e >= 0)" instead of "while (--e >= 1)" I have two more dots, on the top. Why?

If you know some articles or tutorials, would you give me the link to them. Preferably without the use of the frameworks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some trigonometry to simulate 3D dots with a light source.

**[HERE IS AN ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/vgpskqyL/)**

This is one way you can do it, there are of course others (this was the first that came to mind):

- Draw the grid with some dots on the main canvas
- Render a radial gradient to an off-screen canvas
- Change composition mode so anything is draw on already existing pixels
- Calculate distance and angle to light source and draw the dot to each grid point offset with the angle/dist.

Here is some code from the demo that does this.

**Draw the grid with dots**

We skip one grid point as we will fill each dot later with the gradient dot which otherwise would paint over the neighbor dot.

```
/// draw a grid of dots:
for (y = 0; y < ez.width; y += gridSize * 2) {
    for (x = 0; x < ez.height; x += gridSize * 2) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x + offset, y + offset, radius, 0, arcStop);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

**Create a light "reflection"**

Prepare the gradient dot to an off-screen canvas (`dctx` = dot-context). I am using easyCanvas for the setup and to give me an off-screen canvas with center point already calculated, but one can setup this manually too of course:

```
grd = dctx.createRadialGradient(dot.centerX, dot.centerY, 0,
                                dot.centerX, dot.centerY, gridSize);
grd.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
grd.addColorStop(0.2, '#777'); // thighten up
grd.addColorStop(1, '#000');

dctx.fillStyle = grd;
dctx.fillRect(0, 0, gridSize, gridSize);
```

**Do the math**

Then we do all the calculation and offsetting:

```
/// change composition mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';

/// calc angle and distance to light source and draw each
/// dot gradient offset in relation to this
for (y = 0; y < ez.width; y += gridSize) {
    for (x = 0; x < ez.height; x += gridSize) {

        /// angle
        angle = Math.atan2(lightY - y, lightX - x);
        //if (angle < 0) angle += 2;

        /// distance
        dx = lightX - x;
        dy = lightY - y;
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        /// map distance to our max offset
        od = dist / maxLength * maxOffset * 2;
        if (od > maxOffset * 2) od = maxOffset * 2;

        /// now get new x and y position based on angle and offset
        offsetX = x + od * Math.cos(angle) - maxOffset * 0.5;
        offsetY = y + od * Math.sin(angle) - maxOffset * 0.5;

        /// draw the gradient dot at offset
        ctx.drawImage(dot.canvas, x + offsetX, y + offsetY);
    }
}
```

**Shadow**

For the shadow you just inverse the offset while using the composition mode `destination-over` which will draw *outside* the already drawn pixels:

```
/// Shadow, same as offsetting light, but in opposite
/// direction and with a different composite mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';

for (y = 0; y < ez.width; y += gridSize) {
    for (x = 0; x < ez.height; x += gridSize) {

        /// angle
        angle = Math.atan2(lightY - y, lightX - x);
        //if (angle < 0) angle += 2;

        /// distance
        dx = lightX - x;
        dy = lightY - y;
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        /// map distance to our max offset
        od = dist / maxLength * maxOffset * 2;
        if (od > maxOffset * 4) od = maxOffset * 4;

        /// now get new x and y position based on angle and offset
        offsetX = x - od * Math.cos(angle) + gridSize * 0.5;
        offsetY = y - od * Math.sin(angle) + gridSize * 0.5;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x + offsetX, y + offsetY, radius, 0, arcStop);
        ctx.fill();

    }
}
```

This can all be optimized of-course into a single loop pair but for overview the code is separated.

**Additional**

In the demo I added mouse tracking so the mouse becomes the light-source and you can see the dot-reflection changes while you move the mouse. For best performance use Chrome.

To match your need just scale down the values I am using - or - draw to a big off-screen canvas and use `drawImage` to scale it down to a main canvas.

Comment: Thanks @Loktar. It froze? I am testing on an XP now with FF/Aurora and Chrome/relase/canary but I cannot make it freeze. I don't have hardware acceleration which might be a cause (composite modes) but that's just a guess (I'll check if I neglected something with the loops in case they run into some strange condition).

Comment: It didn't freeze, the tab just crashed in Chrome, however after trying again it works perfectly now. Its just something local on my end. Really awesome answer and demo.